# swfobject.embedSWF unable to embed a youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, swfobject

So my html has - 
The swfobject.embedSWF is unable to embed the youtube video.
I have referred to youtube api example for this- https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#onYouTubePlayerReady

Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
       <head>
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id = "ytapiplayer"></div>
          <script>
             var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
             var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
             swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/f4dzzv81X9w?autoplay=1enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                         "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
          </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What error you're getting in the SWF placeholder of your HTML page?

Comment: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/f4dzzv81X9w?autoplay=1enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3" width="425" height="356"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></object>  -- This is the changed html element. And in the console am getting 404 error.

Comment: The Youtube URL that you've quoted http://www.youtube.com/v/f4dzzv81X9w doesn't seems to be working!?

Comment: you mean it gives - this video contains content from UMG?

Comment: I'm getting a `.swf` in return in the `Save As` window

Comment: so that suggests what ?

Comment: I suspect, that URL is a wrong one, probably have a typo error in that. Try including the right one after checking it exists in YouTube

Answer (score 0):

`<object> embeds` have been deprecated since January 27, 2015. See [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Revision_History)

Is there a reason for you using this version?